# Ubuntu (Linux) vs Windows device plug and play compatibility

Tags: drivers, usb, scanner, compatibility

I want to buy a bar code scanner for my web application to read data from cards.

And my user is using Linux and Windows. On some users' computers, no drivers or other software can be installed.

I have decide to get a cheap barcode scanner which is plug and play compatible on Windows.

My question is, can I assume every device which is *plug and play* on Windows will be plug and play on Linux too?

Comment: right, after i read several article about barcode scanner, i notice that usb barcode scanner is act like usb keyboard. but at the same time, i read that some of this device provide drivers and compatibility to some spesific OS like windows and mac only.

Comment: I have an Opticom OPI-3601 here, which has no problems on Linux. It just identifies itself as a keyboard. There was an initial problem with the keyboard layout it used, but that was easily fixed by scanning a few configuration barcodes. That would also be an issue on Windows

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Shortest answer:** Yes.

**Longer answer:** Unless the device is brand new, strange, or just something that fell through the gap, anything plug and play on Windows will likely be plug and play on Ubuntu. Don't assume, though!

Plug-n-Play is an interesting term. There are multiple kinds, each doing different things - for example, a device like a keyboard that needs no special driver at all is plug-and-play, but technically so is the device that downloads its drivers through Windows Update.

Anything in the "generic" category will almost always work on Linux straight away. You should be able to plug in almost any keyboard, mouse, flash drive, etc. without any issue. You may get the rare device that doesn't want to work due to some quirk, but these are few and far between.

Things that download drivers in the background (quite a few webcams, printers, etc.) are more of a mixed bag. In my *personal* experience, these have almost always worked fine on Linux, but this is not always the case. You may need to install printer drivers or other things manually if the Linux kernel doesnt come with a working generic.

In your case specifically, I would hazard a guess that your barcode scanner will work just fine under Linux without anything fancy. Unless you got a very high-end (or very weird) barcode scanner, it will just expose itself to your computer as a keyboard. Keyboards don't need anything special, so it should Just Work™.

Comment: thankyou for your answer, that means i just only need to find a cheap USB barcode scanner with plug and play compatibility  and if for some reason the device need driver then, OS will consider it as minor driver download right? also, my bad but do you have some suggestion for fine cheap usb barcode reader which is simple to me, so i can use its spec for considering to another product which is similar and available on my country.

Comment: Unless you are planning to buy a professional barcode scanner (so willing to pay upwards of US$300), any barcode scanner you get will almost certainly work with Linux, even if it needs to download additional Windows drivers (e.g. configuration tools). Most barcode scanners show up as keyboards, which have a generic driver in both Windows and Linux. As for recommendations, I can't really give you any for the low end, sadly.

Comment: thank you very much. I think your answer is already help to ensure me to decide which solution i need to take.[closed]